# HTML, Javascript - How to save variable after one click on button

Tags: javascript, button

Help me please. I need to save a variable after I click a button once and work with that saved value after I press button three times. I have a click counter but the variable goes undefined after the 2nd click.

```
if (clicks == 1){var bott(savethis)=correct;}

if (clicks == 3){var potom=this-spatne2;}
```

Comment: Where is your code broseidon?

Comment: `var bott(savethis)` is invalid syntax

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't really know what the code you posted is supposed to do *(it's incorrect in many ways, so it does not really make sense)*, so I'll just try to help you based on what you said in your question and assume this is what you want. Tell me if it isn't:

```js
// Declare these variables outside of the click function
// so that you can access them the whole time
var clicks = 0,
    correct = 42,
    bott;
    
// When the document is ready, execute `init`
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

function init() {
  // When the user clicks on the button, execute `onButtonClick`
  document.getElementById('my-button').addEventListener('click', onButtonClick);
}

function onButtonClick() {
  // Add one to the number of clicks
  clicks++;
  if (clicks === 1) {
    // Notice I did not use `var` here, this is because `var` makes the variable
    // local to the function, and once the function's execution is over, it's destroyed.
    // Since I declared it a the top of this script, this is the one I'm referring to.
    bott = correct;
  } else if (clicks === 3) {
    alert('bott is equal to ' + bott);
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="my-button">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: correct was thought as variable too. I have number on my page that change every time i click on the button. I need to save the number after first click, dont make it undefined after second click and use the saved number after third click.

Comment: @RvL Ok, I edited my answer

Comment: @RvL Good. If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as _Accepted_.